# Where can I check my module information in database?

Tags: 8, database

When I create a module, where does the information of the newly enabled/installed module is stored in the database?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The information is stored in the config table.

Search for the record with name 'core.extension', the related data is an array of all enabled modules with their related weight.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning the `key_value` table entries of the modules. Under collection `system.schema`, the names of the installed modules with their respective schema versions is stored.

Comment: Also, if you export config with `drush` or another tool, it might be easier than looking through the database.  See here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management/managing-your-sites-configuration